# linking to another page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

I want to link from one React page to another on a static site, but my routes keep linking to `/#/info` which doesn't seem to do anything.

my index.js file:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My App.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { HashRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Stream from './Stream.js'
import Info from './Info.js'

function App() {
 return (
  <HashRouter>
   <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component='Stream' />
    <Route path='/info' component='Info' />
   </Switch>
   <Link to='/info'>Info</Link>
   <Stream />
  </HashRouter>
 );
}
export default App;
```

My Stream.js:

```
import React from 'react'

function Stream() {
 return (
  <div>Stream</div>
 );
}
export default Stream;
```

My Info.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function Info() {
 return (
  <h1>Info</h1>
 );
}
export default Info;
```

According to [this](http://www.hackingwithreact.com/read/1/23/creating-a-link-between-pages-in-react-router) the url being rewritten as `/#/info` is expected behavior, but my content is not loading when the link is clicked. I want `<Stream />` to go away and for the contents of `<Info />` to take its place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine if you pass in the actual components rather than their names as strings:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Stream} />
    <Route path="/info" component={Info} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: This renders the content for Info, but how would I make `Stream` content disappear once the link is clicked?

Comment: There's no reason to have the <Stream /> call under the `<Route>`s. You're essentially saying, "render either Stream or Info depending on the route, but then render Stream again after that no matter what"

Answer (score 0):

try using `BrowserRouter`

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
   <BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/' component='Stream' />
       <Route path='/info' component='Info' />
    </Switch>
    <Link to='/info'>Info</Link>
    <Stream />
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't matter though

Comment: BrowserRouter is only for sites that expect dynamic pages. My site is static, so I am using HashRouter